# Moving labels with "easy label engine" tool of QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, annotation, formatting

I am using QGIS 2.6 and looking for an similar tool like "converting label to annotation" as you can find it in ArcGIS Desktop.

The "easy custom labeling" Tool in QGIS seems to come close to the ArcGIS solution. However, after I created my custom label layer I am not able to move my labels at the required location. Even the leaders are pointing in different directions and are not linking the label and the feature on the map.

[image: no label-leader linking]

Especially if features are clustered in one region it is helpful to drag them a little bit apart to make the map clear.

Is there another way to individually format and locate my labels?

Comment: Try this:http://www.sourcepole.ch/new-label-tools-in-qgis .

Comment: Also This:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c0m-0X281o and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXK_0eEH3hc

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment! All tools of the new labeling engine are working when I insert the required columns. What the "easy custom tool" does, ist to create a new layer which one can use like a annotation layer. It contains all information about label formatting, location, font size and so on and I don't need to store formatting data in my original shapefile. 
May it depends on the newer QGIS version that these functionality doesn't work?